# NOT NULL constraint failed: instashot_data.user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am rendering a form and when I am submitting that form getting this error

IntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed: instashot.user_id

models.py

```
class data(models.Model):
 description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

form.py

```
class info(forms.ModelForm):

 class Meta:
    model = data
    fields = ['description','img', ]
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, template_name='website.html'):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = info(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
 else:
    form = info()
 return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

.html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
   {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}





    <button type="submit">Upload</button>       
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why this error is coming

Comment: You are not providing `user` data while creating a model instance. That's why the error.

Comment: i didn't understand what do you trying to say

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: What is unclear? Your model requires data for the `user` field, you are not supplying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def detail(request, template_name='website.html'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = info(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user = request.user
            new_form.save() 
    else:
        form = info()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: how new_form and newform  is different